# bind repeater control value to outside control of repeater

Tags: asp.net, repeater

i am developing website. I have to show image gallery of products using repeater control, i have done it but i also need to show some heading (column name and data)outside of repeater control (gallery), it is actually in the repeater control's data source.I just want to bind it to the label outside label of repeater control.M using query string to show images..Kindly help.My code is as follow:

```
<div class="prodListWrapper">
    <div class="subCatHEader">
        <asp:Label ID="Label2" runat="server" Font-Size="Larger" ForeColor="#0098DA" Font-Underline="False" Font-Overline="False"></asp:Label>
    </div>
    <asp:Label ID="lblMessage" runat="server" Text=""></asp:Label>
    <asp:Repeater ID="rptDisplayProduct" runat="server" OnPreRender=" rptDisplayProduct_PreRender">
        <ItemTemplate>
            <div class="prodBox">
                <div class="prodImgBox"> <a href='<%#"productInfo.aspx?productId="+Eval("productId") %>'>
                            <img runat="server" alt="product" id="img" class="imgprod"            src='<%#Bind("prodImg", "~/prodImages/{0}") %>' />
                        </a>

                </div>
                <div class="prodIdWrap"> <a id="lnkProd" runat="server" href='<%#"~/productInfo.aspx?productId="+Eval("productId") %>'>
                            <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("prodSrNo") %>'></asp:Label></a>

                </div>
            </div>
        </ItemTemplate>
    </asp:Repeater>
</div>
```